# Loading indicators for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, components

I'm looking for nice loading indicators for Silverlight.

I found a few, but all are terrible.

I would like something this - http://preloaders.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if these are among the terrible, but here are a few.

[Silverlight ‘Loading’ Spin Icon in XAML](http://www.buttonchrome.com/post/Silverlight-Loadinge-Spin-Icon-in-XAML.aspx)

[Simple Ajax Style Loading Animation in Silverlight](http://blog.webjak.net/2009/02/04/simple-ajax-style-loading-animation-in-silverlight/)

[Customizable Loading Indicator for Silverlight 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/LoadingIndicator.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the functionality of masking/disabling an area while loading data and displaying a message above it, the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has something like that. It's called `BusyIndicator` there. The default template will show a progress bar, but you can change it to anything you like.

If you're looking for some fancy style/design/animation, I can't help you much. But you can browse the Silverlight galleries out there and look for just any animation then (and not just specifically for a "loading indicator") that you could then use for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are ActivityControl in project template of Business Application (WCF Ria Services).