# Silverlight standart progress bar

Tags: silverlight, xaml, progress-bar

When silverlight app loading we see this progress bar:

[image]

How can I add such progress bar in my app. I know that there is ProgressBar control, but I believe that I can get such style and don't redraw it by hands. Where I can find this style?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538981/loading-indicators-for-silverlight
Check this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check these few links about loading spin:

http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/2009/01/18/Silverlight-Loadinge-Spin-Icon-in-XAML.aspx
http://www.blackspike.com/silverlight/silverlight-spinner
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44885/Customizable-Loading-Indicator-for-Silverlight-3

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, third link is great!